# Twilio.Device.connect() not sending body to Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

I'm developing in JS, React on the frontend, and Node, Express on the backend.

I have a call button that I press that I want to start an outgoing call via Twilio. I've got a Node server with a couple endpoints, one to generate a token and the other is the voice url.

On the frontend, I'm making a `Twilio.Device` and have it logging when it's ready. I click on the button, that hit's Twilio's example SDK function that calls `Twilio.Device.connect()` and I am passing `{number: n}` into it.

On the backend, the request is made and the voice url is hit, but without a body. When I try logging `req.body`, it's just an empty object.

When I try hitting the Node server directly from Postman, with the same body (`{number: '+11231231122'}`) I see everything in the log.

Something is happening between the front and backends, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will be sending the body, but as you are using Express it is likely that you aren't parsing that body properly.

Twilio sends requests as url encoded parameters, so you need to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to parse the body into `req.body` within a request. Try setting your app like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: This issue was resolved a few weeks ago, can't remember what it was off the top of my head, but I do think this was it. Thanks.